# Handling a Response from a Result using match

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return a Result from a function and extract it's return.
I'm using `i32` and a `&str` and I get a mismatch type error in the `match` statment (Can't use two different types in a match).
How do I fix this?

```
fn use_result(par: i32)-> Result<i32, &'static str> {
    if par == 0 {
        Err("some error")                                                
    } else {               
        println!("par is 1");                                            
        Ok(par)            
    }
              
}        
fn main() {
    // Result
    let res = match use_result(1) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => e,
    };
}
//Do something with res: v or res: e
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, every variable has a *single type*. In the code you have now, `res` is either a `&'static str` or an `i32`, which is not allowed.

Your options are:

### Return early

```rust
fn main() {
  let res: i32 = match use_result(1) {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return,
  };
}
```

### Different code in each match arm

```rust
fn main() {
  match use_result(1) {
    Ok(v) => {
      handle_success(v);
    },
    Err(e) => {
      handle_error(e);
    },
  };
}
```

### Return an enum

Enums allow you to express that a type is "one of these possible variants" in a type safe way:

```rust
enum IntOrString {
  Int(i32),
  String(&'static str),
}

fn main() {
  let i_or_s: IntOrString = match use_result(1) {
    Ok(v) => IntOrString::Int(v),
    Err(e) => IntOrString::String(e),
  };
}
```

But this is a bit weird, since `Result<i32, &'static str>` is already an enum, if you want to do anything with an `IntOrString` you'll need to `match` on it later on (or an `if let`, etc).

### Panic

```rust
fn main() {
  let res: i32 = match use_result(1) {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => panic!("cannot be zero"),
  };
}
```

This is more cleanly expressed as `use_result(1).unwrap()`. It's usually not what you want, since it doesn't allow the caller of the function to recover/handle the error. But if you're calling this from `main()`, the error has nowhere else to propagate to, so `unwrap`ping is usually OK.

Comment: Do only reasonable I see is your second option, but then if I want to log  the error, I will have to define some mutable value outside the scope of the match and make the error equal to it in the arm. I'm guessing I should use an enum or even struct for the error variable. Am I correct?

Comment: If you want to log the error then quit the program, you can just have `eprintln!("{}, e); return;` as the body of that match arm (i.e. after `Err(e) => {`)

Answer (score -1):

The use of the `?` operator seems more ideomatic to me:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    // Result
    let res = use_result(1);
    if let Err(err) = res {  // can be omitted if
        panic!("{err}");     // only the Ok result
    }                        // is required
    println!("{}", res?);
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=be0456407cc9b566fe572cab65a93c72)